# How to create Searchable Select Drop down in HTML and CSS using only a select element

Tags: html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, searchable-dropdown

I want this select tag as searchable

How to make this select tag searchable ?

```html
<div>
    <select name="code" id="code">
        <option value="">Select Code...</option>
        <?php
        $rows = ["peter", "jones", "sakthi"];

        foreach ($row as $rows) {   ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change this as searchable but i tried **select2 CND** its affecting my previous CSS.
Kindly suggest me a code for this.

Comment: There is no direct way to make a select field "searchable". If a text input in combination with a [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) doesn't suit your needs - then you will need to build something custom yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without **Select2** / **niceSelect** its not possible.

But their is one way to take `<select>` inside `datalist` tag.

#### Try below code:

```html
<label for="fruits">Select a fruit:</label>
<input type="text" id="fruits" list="fruitList">
<datalist id="fruitList">
    <select>
        <option value="Apple"></option>
        <option value="Banana"></option>
        <option value="Cherry"></option>
        <option value="Date"></option>
        <option value="Elderberry"></option>
        <option value="Fig"></option>
        <option value="Grape"></option>
    </select>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. but i want to select only options i gives on option tag but here user can easily type any other string on the input box.